# Pandas - join item from different dataframe within an array

Tags: python, pandas

I am a first data frame looking like this

```
item_id       | options
------------------------------------------
item_1_id     | [option_1_id, option_2_id]
```

And a second like this:

```
option_id   | option_name
---------------------------
option_1_id | option_1_name
```

And I'd like to transform my first data set to:

```
item_id       | options
----------------------------------------------
item_1_id     | [option_1_name, option_2_name]
```

What is an elegant way to do so using Pandas' data frames?

Comment: Are those lists in that DataFrame?

Comment: Also, please post example DataFrames.

Comment: yes those are DataFrames

Comment: where does 'option_2_name' come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html).

For the record, storing lists in `DataFrames` is typically unnecessary and not very "pandonic". Also, if you only have one column, you can do this with a `Series` (though this solution also works for `DataFrames`).

#### Setup

Build the `Series` with the lists of options.

```
index = list('abcde')
s = pd.Series([['opt1'], ['opt1', 'opt2'], ['opt0'], ['opt1', 'opt4'], ['opt3']], index=index)
```

Build the `Series` with the names.

```
index_opts = ['opt%s' % i for i in range(5)]
vals_opts = ['name%s' % i for i in range(5)]
s_opts = pd.Series(vals_opts, index=index_opts)
```

#### Solution

Map options to names using `apply`. The lambda function looks up each option in the `Series` mapping options to names. It is applied to each element of the `Series`.

```
s.apply(lambda l: [s_opts[opt] for opt in l])
```

outputs

```
a           [name1]
b    [name1, name2]
c           [name0]
d    [name1, name4]
e           [name3]
```